# How to create client certificate for multiple users for Postgresql DB with OpenSSL?

Tags: database, postgresql, server, openssl, ssl-certificate

In my database environment (Postgresql 13 on Oracle Linux 8), i can create a client certificate for specific postgresql db user as below:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -out client.csr \
  -keyout keys/client.key -subj "/CN={db_username}"
```

Though it's working for one username, i wonder if multiple usernames or wildcards can be used. For example, can it be used like :

```
CN=user1,user2,user3
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-cert.html) describes, you can use a map in the `pg_ident.conf` file:

> User name mapping can be used to allow `cn` to be different from the database user name.

So you could use one certificate (with a single name) for several database users.

As an example, the line in `pg_hba.conf` could look like

```
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER   ADDRESS         METHOD
host    mydb      user1  12.34.56.78/32  cert map=mymap
host    mydb      user2  12.34.56.78/32  cert map=mymap
host    mydb      user3  12.34.56.78/32  cert map=mymap
```

Then `pg_ident.conf` might look like

```
# MAPNAME  SYSTEM-USERNAME   PG-USERNAME
mymap      certuser          user1
mymap      certuser          user2
mymap      certuser          user3
```

Here, `certuser` is the common name in the certificate.

Comment: is it possible to use pg_ident.conf mappings with password? It seems we can't use md5 or scram password types for this mappings...

Comment: I have added samples.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it lots of tries, i found out that my connection doesn't care about the CN at my client certificate if i configure **pg_hba.conf** like this:

```
hostssl    all    all    192.168.1.34/32    scram-sha-256     clientcert=1
```

This way, connection can be established as long as required key and certificates are available. In addition, passwords will be required so that makes the connection secure.